# MySQL: How to ask for a date greater than today when a date is in a string

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm try to extract info from a MySQL DB into a MS SQL DB. The DB is a mess and the developer is no longer available.

All dates are in char fields, and I use

```
SELECT concat( mid(DueDate, 7, 4), mid(DueDate, 4, 2), mid(DueDate, 1, 2)) as DueDate FROM TableName
```

to get the date field in a format so MS sql server can import them.

Now, I want to export only the record with the date greater than today, so the questions are:

- What is the equivalent of GetDate() in MySQL?
- Is there a better way to cast the date to make the comparison?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MySQL you can convert a string to a date using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

An example usage is:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
        -> '2004-04-31'
```

To get the current date in MySQL simply use the NOW() function. You can then check if a parsed date is later than today using something like

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2009', '%m/%d/%Y') > NOW()
```

Comment: and do you know the equivalent of GetDate() in MySQL? Can I use >= operator?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL equivalent to getdate() is CURDATE()

```
mysql> select IF(CURDATE()<NOW(), 1, 0);
+---------------------------+
| IF(CURDATE()<NOW(), 1, 0) |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 | 
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select IF(CURDATE()=NOW(), 1, 0);                                                                            +---------------------------+
| IF(CURDATE()=NOW(), 1, 0) |
+---------------------------+
|                         0 | 
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```